# CakePHP 3 - Nested Eager Loading Error

Tags: cakephp, orm, eager-loading

I have 3 tables with many to many relationship:

- users
- groups
- tools

And I have 3 pivot tables for the relationships:

- groups_users
- tools_users
- groups_tools

**I'm trying to get the User -> tools, and the User -> Group -> Tools:**

```
$user = TableRegistry::get('Users')
                        ->find()
                        ->where(['id' => 1])
                        ->contain(['Tools'])
                        ->contain(['Groups.Tools'])
                        ->first();
```

But I get an error: "Groups is not associated with Tools"﻿

I followed all the conventions, I created classes:

- GroupsTable, with the following relation at the initializer method

  ```
  $this->belongsToMany('Tools');
  $this->belongsToMany('Users');
  ```
- ToolsTable, with the following relation at the initializer method

  ```
  $this->belongsToMany('Users');
  $this->belongsToMany('Groups');
  ```
- UsersTable, with the following relation at the initializer method

  ```
  $this->belongsToMany('Tools');
  $this->belongsToMany('Groups');
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurred because I was creating a plugin, then these classes were within the plugins folder.

Then you need to change the table relationships to include the namespace plugin:

GroupsTable, with the following relation at the initializer method

```
$this->belongsToMany('YourPluginName.Tools');
$this->belongsToMany('YourPluginName.Users');
```

ToolsTable, with the following relation at the initializer method

```
$this->belongsToMany('YourPluginName.Users');
$this->belongsToMany('YourPluginName.Groups');
```

UsersTable, with the following relation at the initializer method

```
$this->belongsToMany('YourPluginName.Tools');
$this->belongsToMany('YourPluginName.Groups');
```